# removing space from data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in a following frame: 
        umls

```
134 / head pain   /mental
135/ dizzy   /finding 
136  /dizzy a bit  / symptom
138 / severe nausea / sign
```

I am going to remove spaces before and after "/". The output should be like this:

```
     umls
134/head pain/mental
135/dizzy/finding 
136/dizzy a bit /symptom
138/severe nausea/sign
```

I used the following code:

```
df ['umls'] = df_['umls'].replace (' /', '/').replace('/ ', '/')
```

But it does not work. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) whitespaces with `/` use regex `\s*/\s*'` (`\s*` means zero or more whitespaces):

```
df_['umls'] = df_['umls'].replace('\s*/\s*', '/', regex=True)
print (df_)
                      umls
0     134/head pain/mental
1        135/dizzy/finding
2  136/dizzy a bit/symptom
3   138/severe nausea/sign
```

Also works [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df_['umls'] = df_['umls'].str.replace('\s*/\s*', '/')
print (df_)
                      umls
0     134/head pain/mental
1        135/dizzy/finding
2  136/dizzy a bit/symptom
3   138/severe nausea/sign
```

---

If necessary remove witespaces in start or end strings add [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df_['umls'] = df_['umls'].str.replace('\s*/\s*', '/')
print (df_)
                      umls
0     134/head pain/mental
1       135/dizzy/finding 
2  136/dizzy a bit/symptom
3   138/severe nausea/sign

df_['umls'] = df_['umls'].str.strip()
print (df_)
                      umls
0     134/head pain/mental
1        135/dizzy/finding
2  136/dizzy a bit/symptom
3   138/severe nausea/sign
```

---

Sample data:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame({'umls': ['134 / head pain   /mental', '135/ dizzy   /finding', '136  /dizzy a bit  / symptom', '138 / severe nausea / sign']})
```

Comment: thanks, It replaces "white spaces" with "?" in some of the cells. Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: no, it was my first solution, which was removed after your edit. Now this works perfectly. Test it with `df_` from end of answer.

Comment: do yoou think `134?/?head pain?/?mental`? Or `134/head?pain/mental` ?

Comment: For example, C0007859 /  Neck Pain / sign or symptom replaces C0007859/??Neck Pain/sign or symptom replaces

Comment: Sorry, now understand. Maybe some not standard encoding? If still problem, one possible solution is try replace again `.replace('\?', '', regex=True)`